# The flair shown in the user profile doesn't show the correct reputation

Tags: support, user-profiles

To answer to a question on a different meta site, I looked at my flair on Drupal Answers, and noticed that one out of four flair doesn't report the correct reputation.

[image: flair]

It should not be a problem of cache, because differently all the flairs would show the same reputation, which is not what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flairs are cached for a full 24 hours, so it's normal for the flair .png to lag the actual rep a bit.

Comment: Are those four flairs cached independently?

Comment: yes, they are cached independently

Comment: It's not what I would expect; that is why I was not understanding why the values were different for a single flair.